# I recently took interest in python using python3.8 and I' writing code to store user data and then verify it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code in python3.8 to ask user its Name, email, password and phone and storing then in different .txt file and now i have to verify it . Please help me write this program . I added a path in program. Now i need it to check if program has any pre-stored data like name,email,password and phone.And my working directory also have my program file. When I'm running it just getting to directly 2nd part where it's asking me for authentication. How should i define my program so that path does not include my program and checkpoints but only .txt files.

```
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Class Work\\Project Python\\files'
dir = os.listdir(path)
# Here is the problem
if len(dir)==0:
    with open ('name.txt','w') as Name:
        Name.write(str(input("Name: ")))
    with open('mobile.txt','w') as Mob:
        Mob.write(str(input("Mobile No.: ")))
    with open('email.txt','w') as email:
        email.write(str(input("Email ID: ")))
    with open('password.txt','w') as password:
        password.write(input("password: "))
else: # Authentication
    a= str(input("Enter email ID: "))
    b=input("Enter Password: ")
    with open('email.txt','r') as email:
        x = email.read()
    with open('password.txt','r') as password:
        y= password.read()
    if x==a and y==b:
        with open('password.txt','w') as password:
            password.write(input("New Password  "))
    else:
        c = input("Enter Email ID: ")
        d = input("Enter Phone: ")
        with open('email.txt','r') as email:
            s = email.read()
        with open("mobile.txt",'r') as mobile:
            t = mobile.read()
        if c==s and d==t:
            with open('password.txt','r') as password:
                p = password.read()
            print(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F54tT.jpg)

Comment: The lines ```a==email``` and ```b==phone```will do nothing.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What, exactly, are you having trouble with? Is there a particular error you're getting that you can't figure out? Is there a problem you can't solve? We have no idea how to help you unless you edit your question to be clearer about what you're trying to do.

Comment: You dont need to explicitly use `close()` when you use `with open()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i was able to create this program. I solved the problem by changing the dir(By importing 'os'. And used 'for' command to create a loop.

```
import os
# Setting dir and Changing it to access files from specific folder

path = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Class Work\\Project Python\\files'

os.chdir(path)

# checking if dir has any files

if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0 :
    with open ('name.txt','w') as Name:
        Name.write(str(input("Name: ")))
    with open('mobile.txt','w') as Mob:
        Mob.write(str(input("Mobile No.: ")))
    with open('email.txt','w') as email:
        email.write(str(input("Email ID: ")))
    with open('password.txt','w') as password:
        password.write(input("password: "))

else:

# Authentication
    for i in range(3):

        a= str(input("Enter Email ID: "))
        b=input("Enter Password: ")
        with open('email.txt','r') as email:
            x = email.read()
        with open('password.txt','r') as password:
            y= password.read()

        if x==a and y==b:

        # If successful change password
            with open('password.txt','w') as password:
                password.write(input("New Password  "))
                break
        else:
            print("Try again")
    else:

        # IF not successful Show Password
        # after verification of EMail ID and phone

        c = str(input("Enter Email ID: "))
        d = input("Enter Phone: ")
        with open('email.txt','r') as email:
            s = email.read()
        with open("mobile.txt",'r') as mobile:
            t = mobile.read()

        if c==s and d==t:
            with open('password.txt','r') as password:
                p = password.read()
            print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want just to see how python syntax works... I made a script similar to yours just with less stuff because extending it once you get how this works it's trivial.

```
#Here I declare a writing function:
#it accepts input from the user
#and save it into a file
def write(label,filename):
    text = input(label)
    f = open(filename,'w')
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

#This is a checking function:
#you insert name and password
#it reads the respective files
#if the input are the same of the
#stored one then the test it returns 1
#otherwise a 0 
def check(filename1,filename2):
    name = input('Insert your name: ')
    pas = input('Insert your password: ')
    f1 = open(filename1,'r')
    f2 = open(filename2,'r')
    stored_name = f1.read()
    stored_pass = f2.read()
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    if stored_name == name and stored_pass == pas:
        return 1
    return 0

#Creating and saving the files
namefile = 'Name.dat'
passfile = 'Password.dat'
write('Insert your name: ',namefile)
write('Insert your password: ',passfile)

#Reading and checking
recovery = check(namefile,passfile)
if recovery == 1:
    print ('everything correct')
else:
    print ('wrong ID or pass')
```

Comment: It's better to use boolean variables for return. Also it's better to use `with` statements when you're working with files.

Comment: By the way, it's better practice to use `with open(filename, 'w') as f: f.write(text)` to handle the closing of the file. When the `with` statement goes out of scope, the file is automatically closed. @ p.I.